# How to redirect output for change specific csv column and write into same file. Logically: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$19 = $1} 1' a.csv > toSameFile

Tags: csv, awk, stdout, output-redirect

I need to change specific columns on my csv file and awk command is doing my job.

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$19 = $1} 1' a.csv`

But it prints the result and i need to save it to same file to use the file later.

what i've tried:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$19 = $1} 1' a.csv > a.csv`
but it deleted all content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$19 = $1} 1' a.csv > a.csv
```

any awk:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) &&
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$19 = $1} 1' a.csv > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" a.csv
```

The latter works for any command. You can't just do `cmd file > file` because your shell can do the `> file` part first to init the output file and then when it tries to run the `cmd file` part `file` is already empty as you experienced. The `&&`s are required to ensure the current step succeeded before you do the next step otherwise you could end up zapping your input file and losing all it's contents if `mktemp` or `awk` failed for some reason.